# Start a cloned create-react-app from Github

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I've been trying for a some time to run a relatively simple React app. A co-worker started the project with create-react-app and for some reason my can't start the app.

Here's the error code:

```
Error [ERR_INVALID_PACKAGE_TARGET]: Invalid "exports" main target "index.js" defined in the package config /home/francisco/Desktop/University/Data%20visualization/Bialystok-DataVisualization-Project/node_modules/is-promise/package.json
```

NPM then proceeds to  show the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! data-visualization-project@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

I have already ran the following commands: npm install and then npm start. I have also tried to delete package-lock.json and node_modules and re run npm install, and no solution.

I'm currently running npm version 6.14.4 and node 13.11.0

EDIT: Add files
**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import "handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
// Learn more about service workers:
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "data-visualization-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@handsontable/react": "^3.1.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "handsontable": "^7.4.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you show us what is within your index.js file and in your package.json file please?

Comment: @MattDavis here's the index.js: https://github.com/hayriyigit/Bialystok-DataVisualization-Project/blob/master/src/index.js

and here's the package.json:
https://github.com/hayriyigit/Bialystok-DataVisualization-Project/blob/master/package.json

Comment: Does your node_modules/is-promise/index.js look like so? https://i.imgur.com/G4N9OHY.png

Comment: @MattDavis yes, it looks like that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some issues right now with npm/node and create-react-app. I managed to fix a similar problem by installing node version 12.12.0. Perhaps that might fix your issue.

The ticket for [the issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8896)

Comment: I was using Node version 13.11.0 in Manjaro Linux, decided to switch to Windows 10 where I have installed Node version 10.15.3  and everything worked. Will try downgrading Node in linux to see if that's the issue!

Comment: I have a feeling it will be. Lot's of node v 12.12.0+ dependencies are on fire right now. Let us know if it does fix the problem.

Comment: It's exactly that, downgrading to Node 12.12.0 made the app to start. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

try cleaning the cache first

`npm cache clean --force`

and then do the things u already did :

1. Remove node_modules and package-lock.json
2. `npm i`
3. `npm start`

Comment: Tried, this as well didn't work!I think it's more in the line of Node dependencies failing in recent versions. Thanks for the answer though :D

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall create-react-app with:

```
npm install -g --force create-react-app
```

and it fix them .

If not, be sure that you have is-promise@2.2.2 ald older, by command:

```
npm list is-promise
```